# Show Single Route and Delete Route

Tags: node.js, express, routes

New to nodejs, js and express. I'm having difficulties displaying a single nested document, because there are multiple req.params.id on the query. It works but I receive a weird error. Also need help with the query to remove child doc from parent and deleting it. Error and code follows below.

Route

```
//Show Single Route
router.get("/employee/:id/qcerror/:qcerror_id", isLoggedin, function(req, res){
    Employee.findById(req.params.id, function(err, employee) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
    QcError.findById(req.params.qcerror_id, function(err, foundQcError){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect('back');
        } else {
    res.render('qcerrors/show', {employee: req.params.id, qcerror: foundQcError});
        }
    });
    }
    });
});
```

Form

```
<a href="/employee/<%= employee._id %>/qcerror/<%=qcerror._id%>">
```

Error

```
 message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "app.js" at path "_id" for model "QcError"',
  name: 'CastError',
  stringValue: '"app.js"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'app.js',
  path: '_id',
  reason: undefined,
  model: 
   { [Function: model]
     hooks: Kareem { _pres: [Object], _posts: [Object] },
     base: 
      Mongoose {
        connections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: [Object],
        _pluralize: [Function: pluralize],
        plugins: [Object] },
     modelName: 'QcError',
     model: [Function: model],
     db: 
      NativeConnection {
        base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get a invalid ID.

You could use a Regular Expression if you want to check for a string of 24 hex characters.

```
const checkID = new RegExp("^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$");
```

or

```
const mongodb = require("mongodb"),
objectid = mongodb.BSONPure.ObjectID;

console.log(objectid.isValid('yourObjectID'));
```

Comment: That does not help me, I still don't know how to add a valid objectid to the query,  whne i have two req.params.id

Comment: I noticed when I ran a console.log of req.params.qcerror_id.....it returns an "app.js" ahead of the "qcerror_id" (5ad924324d0db10fe02ab4ad). I thinks that's my problem, but don't know how to solve it